# Import the Cognos 10 Trial GOSALES schema (with data) into Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have installed the Cognos 10.2 Trial version. The installation comes a sample  schema called "GoSales".

I would like to import the GoSales schema into my Oracle database. This will enable me to view the GoSales Schema in a database query tool (i.e. TOAD)

My ultimate goal is to:
- Understand the GoSales schema.
- Make sure that the reports I develop using Cognos Studio are correct by checking the data in the database.

So, how can I import the "Go Sales" schema into my Oracle database?

Comment: What format is the sample schema provided as?

Comment: I do not know .. I do not know how to create a dmp file out of that schema even

Comment: You might want to work on your Google-fu - [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.1.1/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_mm.10.1.1.doc/c_cmm_imprt_xprt_dta_import_and_export_data.html%23cmm_imprt_xprt_dta_import_and_export_data) is #2 when Googling for 'export cognos data'. "Take the pebble from my hand...". :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a compressed file with the Cognos BI samples. I guess you can download this file from IBM. Its name is [`bi_smps_10.2.1_mp_ml.tar.gz`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24036501).

You have to uncompress this file and execute the script `...\win\GOSaleConfig.bat` (for a Windows machine). This script will ask you the connection parameters of your Oracle database and create the schemas with sample data.